# Forms API: 'file' or 'managed_file' type with multiple/unlimited values

Tags: forms, files

I've got a form that needs to have either a 'file' or 'managed_file' type field in it for uploading files via the form. Is there an attribute that can be set on the form item render array that will allow multiple/unlimited files to be uploaded via the one form item?

For example, when you add a new field via the admin UI to a content type, select the 'file' type widget and then in the field settings set the number of values to 'unlimited' - that's the sort of behavior I'm looking for in this file field via the forms API. Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to build this functionality for a custom form using the Forms API, it may not yet be possible.  It's documented on Drupal.org to be an issue. [See this discussion](http://drupal.org/node/331941), the bottom talks about the problems with implementing AHAH with a file field.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Plupload](http://drupal.org/project/plupload) form element. Example of implementation can be found at http://drupal.org/node/1647890